# Vue Router - Url with multiple query parameter as redirect url

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this url : `www.foo.com?redirect=https://bar.com?a=b&b=c&c=d`.

When I get the query param `redirect` I should get the value `https://bar.com?a=b&b=c&c=d`. But I only get the first query param `https://bar.com?a=b`.

I'm doing:

```
const { target } = this.$route.query;
console.log(target); 
// "https://bar.com?a=b" instead of "https://bar.com?a=b&b=c&c=d"
```

Comment: url param should be encoded. `www.foo.com?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%3Fa%3Db%26b%3Dc%26c%3Dd` . This way you will get the right result

Comment: Can you change the code that redirects you to that URL? So it is generated encoded as Jacob says?

Answer (score 0):

The url `www.foo.com?redirect=https://bar.com?a=b&b=c&c=d` is parsed into

```
redirect: https://bar.com?a=b
b: c
c: d
```

You need to encoded the value with, e.g. `encodeURIComponent` in JS. Depend on your server lanaguage, you should use the corresponding method to encode the parameter/

```
encodeURIComponent('https://bar.com?a=b&b=c&c=d')
=> "https%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%3Fa%3Db%26b%3Dc%26c%3Dd"
```